# Exception Handling Anti-patterns: Why log and return null is an anti-pattern

Tags: java, exception

An article on Exception handling anti-patterns mentions (Refer: https://today.java.net/article/2006/04/04/exception-handling-antipatterns) that Log and Return Null is an anti-pattern. The reason given is “Instead of returning null, throw the exception, and let the caller deal with it. You should only return null in a normal (non-exceptional) use case”

According to the article, following code is a bad programming practice and anti-pattern

```
catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  LOG.error("Blah", e);
  return null;
}

catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return null;
}
```

I request some more explanation. I can understand why just returning null is an anti-pattern as it swallows the exception losing the information forever. But with  LOG.error("Blah", e); and e.printStackTrace();, the information is logged or printed and is not lost – so why it is an anti-pattern?

Comment: Where is your caller? What if it's a remote call, or a web-service?

Comment: You are eating up the reason of failure and your client will never get to know why this method call failed....it just failed!!!!!

Comment: Have you ever written code for people other than yourself before?

Comment: I more or less agree with the article, but I don't know the meaning of 'you should only return null in a normal (non-exceptional) use case'. In the normal case you would be returning a non-null value. This kind of double-think seems to be all too common in exception-phobia. The writer is now positing or implying *three* scenarios: exceptional, normal but null-returning, and normal and non-null-returning. Life normally isn't that complicated.

Answer (score 4):

The caller gets no additional semantic information about what error occurred, nor why it occurred.  Did they pass bad input?  In that case, give them a client-focused error (which will translate better across RPC or some other kind of remote-invocation).  Did some dependent upstream service go away?  Throw a semantic exception so that the caller can provide useful feedback to the user (e.g., "The database is unavailable.  Please call the help desk at...").  `null` makes it impossible to respond to errors in meaningful ways - it just becomes the catch-all "an error occurred".

Answer (score 0):

The article referenced conflates the use of exceptions and null usage.  In general swallowing an exception is an anti-pattern.  However, in some situations if the catch block is providing information or side-effects thru other means it is a valid approach.  For example, the code can create an exception handler to a visitor.  Also, throwing an exception is meaningless if there is no one to catch it.  Are there scenarios where this is true?